# WarmUp HTTPTrigger function on deploying to staging slot

Tags: azure-functions, azure-deployment-slots

When I deploy to a staging slot I see a WarmUp HTTPTrigger function. This is not a function that was supposed to add. Why is that?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-warmup?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp

From the above documentation -

> **A warmup trigger is invoked when an instance is added to scale a running function app**. The warmup trigger lets you define a function that's run when a new
> instance of your function app is started.
>
> **Support for the warmup trigger is provided by default in all
> development environments.** You don't have to manually install the
> package or register the extension.
>
> The warmup trigger is only called during scale-out operations, not
> during restarts or other non-scale startups. Make sure your logic can
> load all required dependencies without relying on the warmup trigger.
> Lazy loading is a good pattern to achieve this goal.

More Info - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan?tabs=portal#pre-warmed-instances

Similar SO (may give you a bit more idea on Warmup Function in Staging Slot) - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58301181/9276081

Overall, its a good thing to have but you should know when exactly it gets triggered i.e. during scale-out operations ONLY.